# Artifacts blender cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, artifacts

I did a [Tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CB8_QKQ4eKQ) on YouTube. 
When rendering the animation I got a diagonal line with artifacts.

[image: Render result]

This is a render of 300 samples

[image: 300 samples]

I am fairly new to blender so thought i was doing something wrong. Started over used the correct settings for the project but got the same result at the beginning of the tutorial. Both CPU and GPU render show artifacts.

[image: Render result]

Searched on the internet but couldn't find an answer. Any help is much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I have a feeling it has something to do with camera clipping planes. Not sure though. Could you send the .blend file?

Comment: You're only rendering 1 sample. Cycles can need hundreds or thousands of samples to render an image cleanly. Try upping the number of samples (seen in the *Sampling* panel in your screenshot) to 200 and see if you still get the same result.

Comment: @Ray Mairlot 
This line is from the tutorial;
"Since we gonna be using a lot of emission shaders to pull this effect off, we don't really need that much sampling so this is set to 1."
I already did increase the number of samples did one of 300 and one of 1000 samples and got a slightly better result, but still not perfect.
If i raise up the sampling the animation is not being saved in the render output folder. I still have to learn a lot about blender and i am not that technical sorry for that

Comment: @Alphisto [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=2548" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2548/)

Comment: One sample should be enough if you are only using emissive and transparency shaders, like in this tutorial. I downloaded and rendered your file and I had the same image as your first image, but *without* the diagonal artifact. I rendered on the CPU, because I don't have a supported GPU on this laptop. What happens if you render with the CPU?

Comment: @FunkY In future, you should add the blend-exchange embed code into the question using the [edit] link below it, not as a comment. I have done this for you.

Comment: @lbalazscs i've tried that same result.

Comment: You have the artifacts also on the CPU...? What Blender version are you using? (I use 2.78a on Win 8.1)

Comment: @lbalazscs Yes, also on the CPU, using te latest version 2.78a windows 10. 64 bit

Comment: Very strange. In your place I would check again that I see the artifacts in the file that was uploaded here (you can download again), just to be sure, and if the artifact is there, I would report a bug in the Blender bug tracker, but also warn them that it is not easy to reproduce... There could be some small differences between our setups, for example I use the auto tile size plugin, which replaces the tile settings (I rendered with 32*32 tiles).

Comment: Downloaded the file again. Enabled the tile size plug-in. Used the same settings (32*32) same result. Tried all other tile sizes. Artifact remain. Reported a bug. Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: I did the same tutorial and got these lines when rendering with CPU but rendering with GPU got rid of them.

Comment: @NilsEisen Glad it worked for you. In my case the line shows up in both CPU and GPU render.